# it is possible to get stacktrace of methods calls inside call method?

Tags: c#, stack-trace

I want to add more info to the logger at the call method level, and i need to know if exist possibility to get **StackTrace** of methods calls inside call method.

**UPDATE:** The purpose of this is to draw the flow of all methods called until the certain step inside call method.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
public class Type1
{
    internal string method2_T1() {
        return new Type2().method1_T2();
    }        
}


public class Type2
{
    public string method1_T2()
    {
        return "Type2.method1_T2";
    }       
}



static void Main(string[] args)
{            
     string t = new Type1().method2_T1();

      LogNow();

        ....
}
```

and the result to obtain, when I call **LogNow()**, are:

**StackTrace** of method2_T1()

...

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about wanting the stack traces of method calls inside another method? Unless that method has some kind of logging built-in, I don't think that is possible, the call stack collapses as soon as it gets back to the calling method, therefore doesn't exist anymore. The runtime doesn't hold references to all the used call stacks during a method execution.

Comment: You could(= should) use parameters. Why do you need the stack trace?

Comment: I don't understand your question. A "stack trace" is a snapshot of the _current_ state of the stack. While code is executing in a given method, by definition there can't be a stack trace with any methods called from that method (ignoring recursion, of course). At best, this question is answered simply by "you can't do that". At worst, it's not clear at all _what_ you're actually trying to do. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way. Consider asking help for whatever broader issue it is you're trying to solve.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your question.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy:

```
var stackTrace = new StackTrace(true);
var traceToLog = stackTrace.ToString();
```

The `true` argument says to include the file info.

Answer (score 0):

Todd Sprang's answer is good as the actual answer, but be aware that the stack trace will change in unpredictable ways when you move to a RELEASE build, or use async/await. Don't rely programatically on the answers because you may come unstuck when you put the code into production.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment on the answer you're talking about?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the direct caller of a particular function, in a way Microsoft recommend, there's the useful trick using the [`[CallerMemberName]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx), [`[CallerFilePath]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerfilepathattribute(v=vs.110).aspx), and [`[CallerLineNumber]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerlinenumberattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attributes. Mark up optional parameters like so;

```
public void LogWithCallerInfo(
    string message,
    [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "Caller",
    [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "File",
    [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
    {
        WriteProgressMessage(..., memberName, sourceFilePath, sourceLineNumber);
    }
```

and call like this;

```
LogWithCallerInfo("my message");
```

The three optional parameters will be replaced with the appropriate call info.