# Is there a way to find out if a method is called recursively by the same object?

Tags: c#, recursion, stack

I have an object structure with rare, but possible loops. (Loops are normal.) When going through the structure with a recursive method, loops cause stack overflow. Instead of adding another argument to the involved methods, it'd be nice to find out, whether the current method from 'this' is already on the stack. Is that possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33334490/it-is-possible-to-get-stacktrace-of-methods-calls-inside-call-method may be of interest.

Comment: Maybe you could use `lock` together with `Monitor.IsEntered` to detect this situation...

Comment: @Johnny on the same thread, a lock is useless..

Comment: I am not talking about locking but detecting recursion...

Comment: I had a very similar problem when implementing a deep copy algorithm. When you start going through the structure pass a `HashSet` and add the object into this `HashSet`. When you start going further down structure try to add the current object into the `HashSet` if you fail to add this means you got into a loop. Simple as that and super performant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably go for something like a `ThreadLocal<T>` counter, increase it on calling and decrease it on leaving. This way you can count how many time it entered on each thread separately. This is also way faster than scanning the stack. This can also be used with a boolean, just for recursion check.

```
private ThreadLocal<int> _recursiveCounter = new ThreadLocal<int>(() => 0);

public void MyMethod(int count)
{
    _recursiveCounter.Value++;
    try
    {
        if(_recursiveCounter.Value > 2)
            Trace.WriteLine($"Recursive exceeds 2 with {_recursiveCounter.Value}");

        if(count== 0)
            return;

        MyMethod(count-1);
    }
    finally
    {
        _recursiveCounter.Value--;
    }
}
```

---

Ofcourse you can wrap this in a class and combining it with a `IDisposable`  `using(...)`.

Comment: Well, leaving traces is definitely a solution for the problem. If I understood well, it is not possible via the stack, as only the method, but no object id can be retrieved from a frame. Finally I added a stack variable that records a fingerprint of the method and its arguments, works perfectly. I'll mark this one as an answer, since it inspired the solution, thanks!

Comment: @Lajos, I assume you are talking about StackFrame class. it wouldnt be viable to use it anyway. Because the information may be optimized away by inlining etc and it is heavy to use to start with

Comment: Btw., I think, this problem is similar to the google interview question: with limited hardware resources, can you tell of an arbitrary, single linked chain, if it contains a loop?

Comment: I think the key of this method is that you should use a `ThreadLocal<T>`, so that you are certain that it's the same thread. (so the same stack)

Answer (score -1):

I had a very similar problem and the following is how I solved it. Basically I pass along a `HashSet<object>` and try to add `this` into this object. If it is added then `this` has not been handled yet.

```
// Dummy class representing an element in the structure
public class A : Strcuture { }

// Dummy class representing an element in the structure
public class B : Strcuture { }

// Dummy class representing an element in the structure
public class C : Strcuture { }

// Base Dummy class for Base Structure elements
public abstract class Strcuture {

    public List<Strcuture> Elements { get; } = new List<Strcuture>();


    public void AddElement(Strcuture element) {
        Elements.Add(element);
    }

    public void RecursiveMethod(HashSet<object> recursiveChecker) {
        if(recursiveChecker == null){
            recursiveChecker = new HashSet<object>();
        }

        var addedThis = recursiveChecker.Add(this);
        if(addedThis == false) {
            // this object has already been handled
            // throw exception?? return early etc
            throw new System.Exception("Already handled object");

        }
        foreach (var elem in Elements) {
            elem.RecursiveMethod(recursiveChecker);
        }
    }

}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new A();
        var b = new B();
        var c = new C();
        a.AddElement(b);
        b.AddElement(c);
        c.AddElement(a);
        // now our object structure contains a loop
        // A→B→C→A→B...
        a.RecursiveMethod(new HashSet<object>());
    }
}
```

Comment: To the downvoter, If you could write what you think is the problem with this working example, I could fix it